# ActionScript 3, Flash Player 10 - 3d carousel changes perspective, alignment issues

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d, alignment

We made a 3D carousel with the new native 3D support from flash. Now when I resize, my carousel should drag along the middle. Which it does fine. But for some reason the perspective doesnt come along, therefore it looks like the more i resize, the more the carousel is leaning to the left side.

The carousel is set up very simple. Everything rotates around the x-axis with a set distance, the x-axis where the objects revolve around is 0. I just move the whole container to middle of the screen.

to illustrate:

http://www.stijlfigurant.nl/stuff/xaxis1.png
http://www.stijlfigurant.nl/stuff/xaxis2.png

is there a way to solve this or should i go back to good old papervision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by setting root.transform.perspectiveProjection.projectionCenter to the center of the stage!

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know quite what to suggest unless you post some code.

There's nothing wrong with Papervision, but it's probably overkill for a simple carousel. Lee Brimelow has a good tutorial for a 3D carousel here: http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play?id=92 which drags around without distortion quite nicely. (It might be worth noting that the 3D carousel is **way** overplayed, but that's as may be.)

Comment: yea i dont like carousels either - but clients do ;)